# JTextField focus question

Tags: java, swing

Was wondering if it is possible to initialize a text field with printing (this part I know how to do), but then have the printing highlighted, and then disappear when the user starts typing?  Even without the highlighting, how can you have the field initialize with something like,"  Please enter your phone number", and then have that disappear so the the user doesn't have to delete the text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is another approach, with the focusGained event. 
Just mark the initial Text:

```
   String initialText = "Enter your story here...";
   ...
   jTextArea1.setText(initialText); 
   ...

   private void focusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
        if (jTextArea1.getText().equals(initialText)) {
            //jTextArea1.setSelectionStart(0);
            //jTextArea1.setSelectionEnd(jTextArea1.getText().length());
            jTextArea1.selectAll();
        }
    }
```

This way whenever the user types something in the jTextArea1 the initial text will be substituted immediately.

Comment: Or just call selectAll() on the JTextArea rather than setting selection start and end.

Comment: Thanx! selectAll() is better.

Comment: I actually ended up going with the suggestion from Costis.  Works like a charm.  Thanks!  Now to figure out the last 2 bugs, then I'm done.

Answer (score 5):

- Initialize the `JTextFiled` instance with some known text like "Please enter your phone number"
- Implement [FocusListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusListener.html)
- In focusGained() check the JTextField instance to see if it has the known text and if it does clear the text; if not, do nothing.

Here's a code sample

```
    final String INITIAL_TEXT = "Please enter your ph. number";
    final JTextField textField = new JTextField(INITIAL_TEXT);
    textField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            if (textField.getText().equals(INITIAL_TEXT)) {
                textField.setText("");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: holy crap. Thank you!  Sorry, but what is the @override?

Comment: it's an annotation. Here's the documentation for it. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html

Comment: Hmmm....I am trying to write a program to get a name in the textfield, actually, and when I lose focus without a name in the field, I am supposed to prompt for a name.  Now when I do as suggested above, I lose functionality in my combobox (however my JList is still functional, as is my checkbox).  What gives with that?   I have this coded for my focus lost:

Comment: public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource()==gui.regPanel.regTextField
        &&gui.regPanel.regTextField.getText().trim().equals(""))
        {
            gui.regPanel.regTextField.setText(ERROR_TEXT);
            gui.regPanel.regTextField.requestFocusInWindow();
        }         
    }

Comment: can you post the code in the question area if the issue is still related to the original question? If not, you might want to post a new question with a link back to this one.

Comment: @unit: don't forget to upvote shadowfoxmi's post, and then to accept it if you feel that it represents the answer to the original question.  He should get the upvote regardless of whether or not you accept it just for the effort he has put in to help you.

Comment: I would like to upvote alot of people, but I can't seem to get my Open ID to register.  After I actually finish my homework (which is a bit of a priority right now) I will spend some time figuring out what the problem is and why I can't register.  Thanks for checking up, though.

Answer (score 2):

and in `focusLost` it's good usability to put the initial text back if the user did not input anything. Like so:

```
public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)
{
    // If the field is empty, set the default text when losing focus.
    if (inputField.getText().isEmpty())
    {
        inputField.setText(INITIAL_TEXT);
    }
}
```

Or, if you don't want to use the `focusLost` method, you can create an inner class `MyFocusListener` that extends `FocusAdapter`, that way you only need to implement the methods you intend to use.

```
private class MyFocusListener extends FocusAdapter
{
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e)
    {
        // do your magic!   
    }

    // ignore the focusLost method
}
```

Comment: The Adapter thing doesn't gain you too much in this case since it's only two methods, but the Adapter pattern exists for most of the Listener interfaces. Especially MouseAdapter is very useful in that it implements both MouseListener and MouseWheelListener and you only implement the methods you like out of all the mouse actions (there's quite a few of them)

Answer (score -1):

```
public boolean isCorrect() {
    data = new String[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < informationLabel.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            if (!informationTextField[i].getText().equals("")) {
                data[i] = informationTextField[i].getText();
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        if (i == 1 || i == 2) {
            if (informationPasswordField[i - 1].getText().equals(""))
                return false;
        }
        if (i == 3 || i == 4 || i == 5 || i == 6) {
            if (!informationTextField[i - 2].getText().equals("")) {
                data[i - 1] = informationTextField[i - 2].getText();
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```